# Linq SQL select conditions second list level

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have three classes, Sql with foreign keys.

```
public School  
{  
 int id;
 List<Room> Rooms;
}

public Room
{  
 int id;
 ind idSchool;
 List<Chair> Chairs;
}


pulic Chair
{
 int id;
 int idRoom; 
 int legs;
}
```

when I make the request for schools to database using linq, returns all elements ( each school with all rooms and each room with all chairs)

I want Schools with Rooms with only three-legged chairs.(remove from the Schools all chairs.legs!=3)

Comment: show your linq query and where are you stuck?

Comment: I can't make this linq query. Something like this:
 List<School> listSc= db.Schools.Where(s=>s.Rooms.Where(r=>r.Chairs.Where(c=>c.legs==3))).ToList();

This is wrong, the Where condition need's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schools that contain at least one room with at least one three-legged chair:

```
var filteredSchools = schools.Where(school => 
                        school.Rooms.Any(room => 
                          room.Chairs.Any(chair => chair.legs == 3)));
```

You mentioned that you're getting this from a database, so to remove the three-legged chairs, you can try something like this:

```
var chairIdsToRemove = filteredSchools.SelectMany(school => 
                                  school.Rooms.SelectMany(room => 
                                  room.Chairs.Where(chair => 
                                  chair.legs != 3).Select(chair => chair.id)))
                                .ToList();

// Remove chairs with ids in chairIdsToRemove from the database.
```

Comment: Yes "Schools that contain at least one room with at least one three-legged chair", but is incomplete. I want remove chairs with legs != 3